# Plotly horizontal bar plots giving unexpected results

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar plot similar to [this one](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality).

I can generate a vertical plot, but when I change it to horizontal the plot is a mess. I'm trying this two ways, using `go` and `px`. I don't understand the problem and am not sure how to proceed. Here is my code:

Using `go`:

```
import pandas as pd
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dfs = pd.read_html('https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality', header=0)
df = dfs[0]

df['Case-Fatality'] = list(map(lambda x: x[:-1], df['Case-Fatality'].values))

df['Case-Fatality'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Case-Fatality'], downcast='float')
df_sort = df.sort_values(by='Case-Fatality')
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=df_sort['Country'],
    y=df_sort['Case-Fatality'],
    ))
fig.update_layout(
    title='',
    xaxis_title='',
    yaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

Using `px`:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df_sort, x='Country', y = 'Case-Fatality', orientation='h')
fig.show()
```

Following the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/), I should be able to add `orientation='h'` argument to either `go.bar` or `px.bar`. When I do, there is no error but the plot does not look correct.

Here is vertical, plotted properly but not the preferred orientation:
[image]

Here is with the horizontal orientation, it looks the same with either `go` or `px`:
[image]

Any help or guidance on why this is not working would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change x and y values around in either `go.bar` or `px.bar` (still add `orientation = 'h'`).

Both methods work identically well.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What an obvious and sensible solution--the x and y actually change in the graph. Thanks a bunch.